# How to parse JSON datetime string in python?

Tags: python, json

From python I am making a call to a remote API which returns data in a JSON format. I then parse the data using the json module with json.loads(). The problem I am having is with dates - the system I am calling returns the date formatted like the following:

```
/Date(1354011247940+0000)/
```

which json.parse just parses out as a string. How can I convert this to a python date time object?

Edit: unlike [Convert JSON to Python object: how to handle DateTime conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362312/convert-json-to-python-object-how-to-handle-datetime-conversion), I have no control over the data being sent, so I can not simply change the format prior to serializing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get unix timestamp with a regex from this date, then use datetime module to convert it to readable format:

```
>m = re.search(r"Date\((\d+)\+", 'Date(1354011247940+0000)')
>print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(m.group(1))/1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
2012-11-27 12:14:07
```

UPD: note , that you also have milliseconds in this date, they will be truncated by this code

Comment: What should be the other way around...given that I have mm-yyyy formatted date and I want to convert it into a date object like xxxxxxxxx ..?

Comment: In order to read negative number (i.e.date before 1 Jan 1970) change regex to like re.search(r"Date\(([+-]\d+)\+", 'Date(1354011247940+0000)')
Please note added [+-] to read the sign.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Convert JSON to Python object: how to handle DateTime conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362312/convert-json-to-python-object-how-to-handle-datetime-conversion)?

This looks very similar - and an alternative way to what moonsly provided, although, I think moonsly has provided a more 'pythonic' approach than what is provided in the other similar thread (IMO)

Comment: Yes, I looked at that - but the accepted (and only) answer says to change the format of the string when serializing, which is not an option here. I have no control over the data or how it is serialized.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't add this to the comments of moonsly's answer (no rep), so I made it a separate answer.
Just wanted to add a few things others may find useful.
I had this same issue but the json dates were appearing in my data a little differently (ie no + sign):

```
/Date(1416458650000)/
```

There are 9 or 13 character strings. The 9 char strings don't need to be divided by 1000.0.
I also didn't use regex to extract the time string.

```
MILLISECONDS = '/Date(1416458650000)/'.split('(')[1][:-2]
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(MILLISECONDS)/1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
2014-11-20 15:44:10
```

I can also do

```
SECONDS = '/Date(1416458650000)/'.split('(')[1][:-5]
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(SECONDS)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
2014-11-20 15:44:10
```