# How to parse Date(928142400000+0200)?

Tags: python, json, rest, python-datetime, datetime-parsing

I have JSON response object with string representing date and time:

```
"event":{
    "type":"Type",
    "date-time":"\/Date(928142400000+0200)\/",
},
```

I am not sure:

- what format is that
- how can I parse it in python app
- how can I convert python date into this format

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can see what you are looking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591858/how-to-parse-json-datetime-string-in-python).

Answer (score 4):

`928142400000` is the time in milliseconds since the UNIX epoch, `+0200` is the timezone.

With the [`dateutil` library](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-8bf499d888b70bc300c6c8820dc123326197c00f) or [`datetime.timezone()` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects) you can model the timezone offset, the timestamp itself is parsable with [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp), provided you divide the value by 1000.0:

```
import datetime
import re

timestamp_parse = re.compile(r'Date\((\d+)([+-]\d{4})\)')
timestamp, offset = timestamp_parse.search(datetime_value).groups()
tzoffset = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(offset[1:3]), minutes=int(offset[3:]))
if offset[0] == '-':
    tzoffset *= -1
tzoffset = datetime.timezone(tzoffset)
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp) / 1000.0).replace(tzinfo=tzoffset)
```

The [`dateutil.tz.tzoffset()` object](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-8bf499d888b70bc300c6c8820dc123326197c00f) version is similar:

```
import datetime
import re
import dateutil.tz

timestamp_parse = re.compile(r'Date\((\d+)([+-]\d{4})\)')
timestamp, offset = timestamp_parse.search(datetime_value).groups()
tzoffset = int(offset[1:3]) * 3600 + int(offset[3:]) * 60
if offset[0] == '-':
    tzoffset *= -1
tzoffset = dateutil.tz.tzoffset(None, tzoffset)
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp) / 1000.0).replace(tzinfo=tzoffset)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import re
>>> datetime_value = "/Date(928142400000+0200)/"
>>> timestamp_parse = re.compile(r'Date\((\d+)([+-]\d{4})\)')
>>> timestamp, offset = timestamp_parse.search(datetime_value).groups()
>>> tzoffset = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(offset[1:3]), minutes=int(offset[3:]))
>>> if offset[0] == '-':
...     tzoffset *= -1
... 
>>> tzoffset = datetime.timezone(tzoffset)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp) / 1000.0).replace(tzinfo=tzoffset)
datetime.datetime(1999, 5, 31, 10, 20, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)))
```

Comment: there is a bracket left in answer.